# Is a set of positive linear combination of basis of a finite dimensional vector space is an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

### Is the following statement true?

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then,
>    $$\left\{z=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i: \alpha_i>0\quad \forall\; i\right\}$$
>     is an open set.

Comment: With respect to what topology?

Comment: @user399625 Usual topology.(metric topology) Means you may consider the space as euclidean space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can take $\alpha=\operatorname{min}_i\alpha_i|x_i|$.  Then take an open ball of radius $\alpha/2$.

If this contained a point, call $w=\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_ix_i$, not in the set, then $w$ has some $\beta_i\leq0$, which implies that $d(w,z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\alpha_i-\beta_i\right||x_i|\geq(\alpha_i-\beta_i)|x_i|\geq\alpha_i|x_i|\geq\alpha>\alpha/2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Superb!!! Crispy..Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yet another version of the same argument: The projections $\pi_i\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\pi_i(\sum_k{\alpha_kx_k})=\alpha_i$ are continuous, thus $\pi_i^{-1}((0,\infty))\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open for all $i=1,...,n$. The set under consideration is the  interesection of these sets and thus open as well.

Comment: I think, this is union of these sets@jabo

Comment: No, it's the intersection. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\pi_1^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is the upper halfplane and $\pi_2^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is the right halfplane. You have to intersect them to get the right upper quadrant.

Comment: Yeah...you are right.. All the $\alpha$'s should be positive. Hence, its intersection

Comment: But how are you concluding that arbitrary intersection of open sets is open.

Comment: It's only a finite intersection, if you want to prove that you have to do an argument like @Gaffney.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The positive "octant" is always open.

One argument: the topologies generated by open rectangles and the one generated by open disks are the same (essence of proof: every open rectangle contains an open disk, and vice versa), and the positive octant is clearly a union of open rectangles (indeed, it's a single open rectangle).

(You might argue that you're not asking about the positive octant, but about the positive convex combination of these vectors. But there's an isomorphism taking those vectors to the standard basis vectors; that isomorphism is bicontinuous (being represented by multiplication by an invertible matrix, for instance), hence preserves open-ness.)